# how to create a dependent select 2 drop down in yii2?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii2

I have 2 select 2 drop down list. One is for country and one is for city . So now, I want to select country and my city select 2 should only load all based on my country selection. How is that possible?

Comment: Have you googled this?  Because I just did and found 188,000 results.

Answer (score 1):

You can create form scratch   http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/723/creating-a-dependent-dropdown-from-scratch-in-yii2/  or use a proper extension http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/depdrop

Answer (score 1):

You cand this code in form

```
<?php  $Country= ArrayHelper::map(Country::find()->all(),'id', 'country_name');?>
<?php  echo $form->field($model, 'country')->dropDownList($Country, 
     ['prompt'=>'-Choose a Category-',
      'onchange'=>'
        $.post( "'.urldecode(Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('country/lists&id=')).'"+$(this).val(), function( data ) {
          $( "select#city_id" ).html( data );
        });
    ']); ?>
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'city')->dropDownList(          
    ['prompt'=>'-Choose a Sub Category-'],
    ['id'=>'city_id']
);?>
<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

and create list action in controller

```
public function actionLists($id)
{
    $sql = "select * from city where country_id ='$id' ";
    $models = City::findBySql($sql)->asArray()->all();   
    if(sizeof($models) >0)
    {
        echo "<option value="">-Choose  City-</option>";
        foreach($models as $model)
        {
            echo "<option value='".$model['id']."'>".$model['city_name']."</option>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<option>-Choose a Sub City-</option><option></option>";
    }

}
```